Was Pradyumna ever defeated in battle?
Pradyumna, the son of Rukmini and Krishna, is renowned for his strength and valor, and I have not encountered any instance where he was defeated in battle. Below are four notable instances where he either achieved victory or played a significant role in battle:
#1: War with Sambara

The demon (Śambara) then unleashed hundreds of mystic weapons
belonging to the Guhyakas, Gandharvas, Piśācas, Uragas and Rākṣasas,
but Lord Kārṣṇi, Pradyumna, struck them all down. Drawing His
sharp-edged sword, Pradyumna forcefully cut off Śambara’s head,
complete with red mustache, helmet and earrings. As the residents of
the higher planets showered Pradyumna with flowers and chanted His
praises, His wife appeared in the sky and transported Him through the
heavens, back to the city of Dvārakā.
[23-25, 55, 10, Srimad Baghavatham]]

#2: War with Salwa
Pradyumna, on Narada and the wind god's advice, spared Salwa, as his death was destined by Krishna. Though he overpowered Salwa and prepared to strike, he withdrew his fatal arrow, honoring the celestial decree, allowing Salwa to escape through the skies.

And these delighting in blood, warding off the shafts of Daitya,
pierced his head, bosom and face. And at those wounds Salwa fell down
senseless. And on the mean-minded Salwa falling down, afflicted with
Pradyumna's arrows, the son of Rukmini aimed another arrow at him,
capable of destroying every foe. And beholding that arrow worshipped
by all the Dasarhas, and flaming like fire and fatal as a venomous
snake, fixed on the bow-string, the firmament was filled with
exclamations of Oh! and Alas! Then all the celestials with Indra and
the lord of treasures (Kubera) at their head sent Narada and the god
of wind endued with the speed of the mind. And these two approaching
the son of Rukmini delivered unto him the message of the celestial,
saying, O hero, king Salwa is nor to be slain by thee! Do thou draw
back the arrow. He is unslayable by thee in fight! There breatheth not
a person who cannot be killed by that arrow! O thou of mighty arms,
the Creator hath ordained his death at the hands of Krishna, the son
of Devaki! Let this be not falsified!--Thereupon with a glad heart,
Pradyumna withdrew that best of arrows from his excellent bow and
deposited it back in his quiver. And then, O foremost of kings, the
mighty Salwa, afflicted with the arrows of Pradyumna, rose
disheartened, and speedily went away. Then O king, the wicked Salwa,
thus afflicted by the Vrishnis, mounted on his car of precious metals,
and leaving Dwaraka scudded through the skies!'"
[Section 19, Arjunabhigamana Parva, Vana Parva, The Mahabharata]

#3: War with Kartikeya
Pradyumna defeated Kārtikeya in battle, forcing him to flee the battlefield on his peacock, wounded and bleeding.

Lord Rudra, accompanied by his son Kārtikeya and the Pramathas, came
riding on Nandi, his bull carrier, to fight Balarāma and Kṛṣṇa on
Bāṇa’s behalf. A most astonishing, tumultuous and hair-raising battle
then commenced, with Lord Kṛṣṇa matched against Lord Śaṅkara, and
Pradyumna against Kārtikeya.....Lord Kārtikeya was distressed by the
flood of Pradyumna’s arrows raining down from all sides, and thus he
fled the battlefield on his peacock as blood poured from his limbs.
[6-7,15, 63, 10, Baghavatha Purana]

#4: War with Nikumbha [91, Vishnu Purana, Harivamsha Purana]
Though Pradyumna lost consciousness like Krishna and Arjuna, he regained his senses and fought till the end. Undeterred by Nikumbha’s illusions, he supported Krishna, who ultimately killed the Asura with his discus. Pradyumna’s resilience ensured he was never defeated in the war with Nikumbha.
I am seeking any instances, if they exist, where Pradyumna was defeated. Please exclude the climax incident from the Mausala Parva. Provide details if available.
